# Turtlebot 4 simulation - rplidar not working

Tags: gazebo, lidar, rviz

I am trying to run a simulation for Turtlebot 4 by following this tutorial, [Simulation](https://turtlebot.github.io/turtlebot4-user-manual/software/simulation.html), and using ros2 humble.

However, I am not able to see lidar rays properly in Ignition Gazebo or get it displayed as dots in Rviz.

I am using this for launching:

```
ros2 launch turtlebot4_ignition_bringup turtlebot4_ignition.launch.py slam:=true nav2:=true rviz:=true
```

When I tried

```
$ros2 topic echo /scan
```

I receive all 0.0 in ranges and -1.0 in intensities.

[image: Screenshot of both Ignition Gazebo and Rviz]

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: Hi Joan, 
Unfortunately I cannot recall how I solved this issue. However, I might be able to remember if you provide me with further information like your setup, the way you installed the packages, and some screenshots, and logs.

Comment: I think I remembered where the issue was. The Gazebo LIDAR plugin is set to use the GPU for the Turtlebot4 simulator. Make sure you have a driver running and your GPU is fully functional. To check that you can go to your settings in Ubuntu -> about> Graphics. It should show you something like Nvidia... if it is working. Again, I am not quite sure about it so I would appreciate it if you provide some more information. In case the GPU is the problem, please let me know to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

I [found out](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/issues/38) that in some PCs it is necessary to export the environment variable `IGN_IP=127.0.0.1` to avoid the endless message "Requesting list of world names....".

Also, in my case I had an open software driver running (not the nVidia) but without permission to change it. So the workaround I found [here](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sensors/issues/26#issuecomment-1309563861) is to make the GPU ray work in CPU exporting the environment variable `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=true`.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics,* joanvallve. If these are the steps you took to solve the same problem then they don't need to be made a comment, they're the answer!